# How to trim substring from string with the condition of being found at the end of it?

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace, string-matching

For instance, this would be the criteria for my condition of trimming:

The substring `2` preceeded by a space would be removed from the end of the string, but *not* if it is found inside the string and before its end.

`The date is 2015` would remain the same, but not the string `the date is 2015 2`, from which the space and the `2` at the end of it should be trimmed

I am aware that I could half-bake something with `explode`/`implode` functions, but is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: `rtrim($txt, " $foo");`

Comment: I was about to post `^.*(\ 2)$` regular expression that works multiline but @Dagon posted an actual answer as a comment :D

Comment: Oh, how silly of me, you're saying that there's an actual PHP function for this exact purpose? :) Thanks! @dragon

Comment: well i was not 100% sure this would work as the op wanted so it was posted as a comment, will post as ans for OP to pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rtrim($txt, " $foo");
```

trims the selected characters from the right of the string